# how to set baseurl while deployment in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, base-url

this is my url 
https://abc.com/project/projectfolder/public/

its shows 404 not found error
there is two .htacess one is under public folder and other is under projectfolder
now please let me know what to do

This is .htacess

Options +FollowSymLinks Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR] RewriteCond
%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d RewriteRule ^.*$ – [NC,L] RewriteRule ^.*$/index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

ommit the leading slash in last rule:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
```

Comment: its shows the css part on my page but its never load the index controller. Is there any need to change in application.ini file for url?